# Можно ли в XSD описать правило сравнения двух полей?

Tags: xml, валидация, xsd, validate

У меня есть XML файл.
Нужно проверить 1) валидность структуры, данных, 2) соотношение двух полей типа дата
Для п.1 описал XSD.
В XML есть поля даты, например, ValidFrom и ValidTo.
Нужно добавить проверку, что ValidTo не раньше, чем ValidFrom
Но не мону понять, можно ли в XSD описать такую проверку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно  ли как-то с помощью XSD решить мою задачку?
Кажется, что где-то читал раньше, что в XSD можно добавлять поля типа Calculation (рассчитываемые), но сейчас не могу найти такую информацию.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255905/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks. Sorry, I am a new in XML/XSD.   
I tried to use that code for attributes like that, but I have got the error  
"s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_DocumentUsermessagefinmessage' is invalid. Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.xsd(s4s-elt-invalid-content.1)
This type is extended by all types which allow annotation other than itself
This type is extended by almost all schema types to allow attributes from other namespaces to be added to user schemas."

Comment: Вам нужно использовать XSD 1.1, XSD 1.0 не поддерживает то, что вам нужно. В XSD 1.1 есть `assert` для ваших нужд.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
(1) Правильно сформированный входной XML (well-formed).
(2) Ваша логика и XSD, который пытался ее реализовать.
(3) Процессор XSD и его соответствие стандартам XSD: 1.0 или 1.1.